# Reading from IStream into std::ifstream

Tags: winapi, istream

I am writing a Preview Handler for a file with custom extension.

The Preview Handler implements IInitializeWithStream interface which initializes IStream with file data which has been selected in windows explorer.

Now, I need to perform some parsing operations on this data stream (the data in the file is plain text in a predefined custom format).

In order to do that, I need the data in std::ifstream object so that i can easily use STL on it to achieve the desired output.

Long Story Short: I need a way to convert/fill the data from IStream to std::ifstream.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem. I saw a recommendation to implement a wrapper using http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iostreams/doc/tutorial/container_source.html . How did you solve this?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, all you have to do is:

    `is << file.rdbuf();`

Comment: @user643011:I used the Read method of IStream interface to fill the data into char buffer and stream it into std::ostringstream using "<<" operator.

Comment: @0x499602D2: I think your suggestion is what I did (I am not sure though). Anyways thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the Read method of IStream interface to fill the data into char buffer and stream it into std::ostringstream using "<<" operator